# generator functions in Python

Tags: python, function, iterator, generator, string-matching

I am currently working through one of the problem sets on MIT OCW, the task is to find matching substrings in DNA sequences.

I am struggling to write a function that returns subsequences of length k. I can get it to work when using a string but the problem is set up with an iterator, when using an iterator the function seems to reset every time instead of going back to its original position with yield.

Here is a correct function I have written that uses a string:

```
def subs(seq, k):
    subseq = ''
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(seq):
        while len(subseq) < k:
            subseq += seq[pos]
            pos += 1
        yield subseq, pos - k
        subseq = subseq[1:]
```

A correct answer:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> b = subs(a,2)
>>> b.next()
('he', 0)
>>> b.next()
('el', 1)
>>> b.next()
('ll', 2)
>>> b.next()
('lo', 3)
>>> b.next()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    b.next()
StopIteration
```

**My Problem**

The task is set up using a class that creates an iterator out of a long string sequence, I won't go into it here but the test given also creates an iterator from a string

```
# This test case may break once you add the argument m (skipping).
class TestExactSubmatches(dnaseq.unittest.TestCase):
   def test_one(self):
       foo = 'yabcabcabcz'
       bar = 'xxabcxxxx'
       matches = list(dnaseq.getExactSubmatches(iter(foo), iter(bar), 3, 1))
       correct = [(1,2), (4,2), (7,2)]
       self.assertTrue(len(matches) == len(correct))
       for x in correct:
           self.assertTrue(x in matches)
```

and my current solution:

```
def subsequenceHashes(seq, k):
    subseq = ''
    pos = 0
    print 'Start of subseqHashes'
    try:
        while True:
            while len(subseq) < k:
                subseq += seq.next()
                pos += 1
            print subseq, pos - k
            yield hash(subseq), pos - k
            subseq = subseq[1:]
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

The function calling it gets the hash of the subsequences, puts them along with the position of where the subsequence starts into a dictionary (the class multidict) and compares substrings with the same hash to see if they are the same. It should then return pairs of positions in both strings of substrings that are the same. I haven't managed to debug most of this function as I am having problems with the start of it.

```
def getExactSubmatches(a, b, k, m): 
    # a and b are the strings compared, k is the length of substring, parameter m is unused, need it for later on in the problem set
    ahash, apos = subsequenceHashes(a, k).next()
    bhash, bpos = subsequenceHashes(b, k).next()
    multidict = Multidict()
    print 'starting'
    while ahash:
        print 'iterate'
        multidict.put(ahash, ('a', apos))
        ahash, apos = subsequenceHashes(a, k).next()
        print apos
    while bhash:
        multidict.put(bhash, ('b', bpos))
        bhash, bpos = subsequenceHashes(b, k).next()
    for key in multidict.mydict:
        if len(multidict.get(key)) > 1:
            for t in multidict.get(key):
                if t[0] == 'a':
                    for s in multidict.get(key):
                        if s[0] == 'b':
                            if a[apos:apos+k] == b[bpos:bpos+k]:
                                print apos, bpos
                                yield apos, bpos
```

What happens when I run the test:

```
Start of subseqHashes


yab 0
Start of subseqHashes


xxa 0
starting
iterate
Start of subseqHashes


cab 0
0
iterate
Start of subseqHashes


cab 0
0
iterate
Start of subseqHashes


F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_one (__main__.TestExactSubmatches)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Pythonwork\6.006\ps4\dist\test_dnaseq.py", line 32, in test_one
    self.assertTrue(len(matches) == len(correct))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

What seems to be going wrong is subsequenceHashes is being reset every time i use .next() when its got an iterator in its body as opposed to staying in the loop when using a string.

Comment: Every time you call e.g. `subsequenceHashes(b, k)` it will start again. You should create them once, at the start of the function.

Comment: The sequences of DNA that i will be comparing are tens of millions of nucleotides long, the problem set recommends making generator functions. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps4.pdf

Comment: Yes, but you should *only call the generator function once*. After that, you only want to *iterate over it*, not keep restarting it. Start with `gen_a = subsequenceHashes(a, k)` and go from there.

Comment: Note that a string with only tens of million characters fits very easily in memory.  You should first try the simple solution, and only switch to generators/iterators if you really have memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, my mistake was calling the generator function multiple times and not actually iterating over it.